# Error while upgrading to SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

We have few legacy sites in SharePoint 2010, which we are migrating to SP 2013.

One of the site collection contains a Custom List with **Issue** content type attached to it.

The list works fine in 2010, However, when we migrated the site to 2013 its throwing error:

```
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.


Correlation ID: 5d6b0f9e-0a04-90d1-0b09-d089c7663762
```

I tried creating a new Custom List in 2013 and added Issue content type to that list. But that is also throwing same error, so its not a migration issue.

I want to check if this is specific to 2013 and has anyone faced this issue before?

**Edit: ULS Log**

```
Error while executing web part: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.SPGridSerializerGenerator.IsReadOnlyField(SPField field)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart.AddInFieldSchemaForIPE(SPList list, XmlNode fieldRefNode, SPField field)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart.AddInFieldSchema(XmlNodeList fieldRefNodes, SPList list)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart.AddInTypeInfoIntoViewXml(XmlNode viewXml)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart.ModifyXsltArgumentList(ArgumentClassWrapper argList)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform)   5d6b0f9e-0a04-90d1-0b09-d089c7663762
```

Comment: Can you please share ULS logs with this correlation id?